# Packages installed on Anaconda, but can't access in Spyder or Jupyter

Tags: python, anaconda

I have the plotly package installed on anaconda, I can see this on my base (root) environment within Anaconda navigator.

However, when I try to import the package on Spyder/Jupyter this following occurs,
**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'retrying'**

Do you know of anyway I could check why this hasn't updated Spyder/Jupyter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please show how you attempted to import the package on your respective IDE, whether Spyder/Jupyter. Do comply to SO's guidelines before posting questions.

Without delay, this may be an error due to missing module `retrying`, a dependency for `plotly`

To solve this, please attempt to install `retrying` via `pip install retrying`

Answer (score 0):

You can open a terminal in the top right corner of the window of Jupyter (new --> Terminal). There you can pip install plotly. Restart Jupyter and it should be okay. :)